Invalid subscriptionPricePoint id eyJzIjoiNjUwNTA0ODMxNiIsInQiOiJBVVMiLCJwIjoiMTAwMDIifQ
API call https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/subscriptions/{id}/pricePoints?filter[territory]=AUS&fields[territories]=currency&fields[subscriptionPricePoints]=customerPrice,equalizations,proceeds,proceedsYear2,territory&limit=1000&include=territory
with these params, I got subscriptionPricePoints this eyJzIjoiNjUwNTA0ODMxNiIsInQiOiJBVVMiLCJwIjoiMTAwMDIifQ for 0.49 but when I added the price for a subscription using this PricePoint it's give me
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "09ac4e92-45f7-4456-a71a-4fd7c83da55c",
            "status": "409",
            "code": "ENTITY_ERROR.RELATIONSHIP.INVALID",
            "title": "The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value",
            "detail": "Invalid subscriptionPricePoint id eyJzIjoiNjUwNTA0ODMxNiIsInQiOiJBVVMiLCJwIjoiMTAwMDIifQ",
            "source": {
                "pointer": "/data/relationships/subscriptionPricePoint"
            }
        }
    ]
}

and my joson for adding price in subscription is this
{
        "data": {
            "type": "subscriptionPrices",
            "relationships": {
                "subscription": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "subscriptions",
                        "id": "6670163991"
                    }
                },
                "subscriptionPricePoint": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "subscriptionPricePoints",
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiNjUwNTA0ODMxNiIsInQiOiJBVVMiLCJwIjoiMTAwMDIifQ"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

I tried with other pricepoint but got the same error, I was expecting it to work with this pricepoint because subscriptionPricePoint is also given by Apple support so,
